What algorithms exist to efficiently capture performance metrics across different time intervals
We have an application server and I wish for it to capture performance metrics so it can report them. By performance metrics I mean things like number of queries, number of insertions, number of deletions, and so forth. These values would be reported over different time intervals. For example, 36 queries/SECOND, or 13000 queries/HOUR.
I want to capture these metrics over different time periods so that we can visualise longer term load and also spikes/peak loads. To that end we would want to show eg. queries per time interval for say 1 second, 5 seconds, 30 seconds, 1/5/15 minutes, 1/4/8/12/24 hours.
(That's just an example, we'd probably reduce the real number down).
For each of the above time intervals I want the counts to reflect the LAST N secs/minutes/hours so the figures all update in real-time (or close to). In other words, a metric such as queries/HOUR means the number of queries in the prior 60 minutes starting from "now".
Obviously I want an efficient algorithm so the "capturing" of the metric is not particularly impactful (performance wise) on the operation of the code itself.
Does anyone know of existing algorithms that solve this requirement?
